# Проверка блокировки MAC OS

Tags: c++, qt, macos

Как проверить заблокирована ли машина на MAC OS?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вам поможет [это обсуждение](https://www.oipapio.com/question-3149501). Плюс, [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851364/report-monitor-resolution-from-macos-in-qt) есть код на Qt, который поможет вам в реализации. Ну и [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505255/osx-check-if-the-screen-is-locked) есть такой же вопрос, но к сожалению, там язык - python.

К сожалению, у меня нет под рукой MacOS, чтобы дать более развёрнутый ответ.